# Add conversion/tracking pixel to <head> section for specific post

Tags: scripts

I need to add a tracking pixel for a Facebook ad to my Wordpress site. It should only be active for one blog post, not for every page on the site.

How can I get the script into the HEAD section for the specific post only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wordpress [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

You can add something like this to your functions.php file:

```
is_single( 'your-post-slug' )
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'your_function_with_pixel' )
```

There are a number of different conditional tags you can use. And your-post-slug can be substituted with the post id as well.